# informix to mariadb - is there a way to replace UNLOAD TO / LOAD FROM

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, informix

I am in the middle of adapting an existing application to use MariaDB instead of Informix.

One thing I noticed, among others is that for backup we are using in our code "UNLOAD TO" statement ( https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=statements-unload-statement ) which has the equivalent in MariaDB "SELECT INTO FILE" ( https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-into-outfile/ )

Since there are many places where the Informix SQL statements are intercalated with other SQL statements like DELETE FROM, SELECT etc the first option would be to adapt the particular Informix SQL to match the MariaDB one.

Is this approach the best I can hope for?
Can I do something like an "UNLOAD adapter statement" which can convert the "UNLOAD TO" statement somehow to be interpreted in MariaDB?

Comment: If all your `UNLOAD` statements are formatted the same, you could probably write a script to replace them with equivalent `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` statements.

Comment: You may find some useful tools by googling "convert informix to mysql"

Comment: @Barmar, as you might suspect there are many differences between the two, this one being one of them. Sadly there was no clear separation between these "maintenance operations" and other normal SQL statements, so we're kind of caught in the middle of some old decisions which affect us now.

Comment: Just converting these UNLOAD statements is the least of your problems. SQL dialects are all different enough that it's not really possible to run code intended for one in another. You'll need to use a conversion tool.